# k8s - Redirect all traffic from namespace X to Y

Tags: kubernetes

I have 2 microservices in different namespaces:

```
ns     | deploy  | svc
my-app | my-app  | my-app
my-appz| my-appz | my-appz
```

On namespace my-app, I have change my Service from `ClusterIp` to a `ExternalName` Service resolving all traffic to my-appz:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-app
  namespace: my-app
spec:
  externalName: my-appz.my-appz.svc.cluster.local
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: http
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ExternalName
```

But when I check logs from pods on namespace `my-app`, I see that pods still receiving traffic even after I change the service to ExternalName. How is that possible?

Is there any way to resolve all traffic from `my-app.myapp.svc.cluster.local` / `my-app.my-app` automatically to `my-appz.myappz.svc.cluster.local`?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the same problem, mimicking what you have done, and its working as expected.  Although I would suggest making sure that you are not doing any type of. For example, in the 2nd last line of the question, you have said `myapp` but everywhere else, its `my-app`

Comment: I mean, **typo**